# Adwhirl does n't show ads from ad mob and same time it show house ads

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl

now i've been tring to integrate adwhirl to my application it does not show any add from the admob provider.But it will show house ads does not seem any problem with that

I added log cat file

To verify working of admob I interated with the same application too it does n't show any problem

Any help will be appreciated

thanks in advance

```
11-19 15:18:33.149: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(572): Showing ad:
11-19 15:18:33.149: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(572):     nid: 95eb0bdbbc484f8a86e69d15e04f7644
11-19 15:18:33.149: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(572):     name: admob
11-19 15:18:33.149: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(572):     type: 1
11-19 15:18:33.149: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(572):     key: a14ce50397c3043
11-19 15:18:33.149: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(572):     key2: 
11-19 15:18:33.149: INFO/dalvikvm(572): Failed resolving Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/AdMobAdapter; interface 88 'Lcom/admob/android/ads/AdListener;'
11-19 15:18:33.149: WARN/dalvikvm(572): Link of class 'Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/AdMobAdapter;' failed
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572): Caught an exception in adapter:
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572): java.lang.Exception: Invalid adapter
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at com.adwhirl.adapters.AdWhirlAdapter.handle(AdWhirlAdapter.java:141)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.handleAd(AdWhirlLayout.java:163)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.access$3(AdWhirlLayout.java:151)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$HandleAdRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:316)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-19 15:18:33.159: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(572):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code is added below

```
private static final String COMPANY_NAME = "soft";
private static final String APP_NAME = "firstapplication";
private static LogindbAdapter dbAdapter;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AdManager.setInTestMode(true);


    AdView adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
    adView.requestFreshAd();

    dbAdapter=new LogindbAdapter(getBaseContext());
   LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_ad);

    try 
    {


        AdWhirlAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseCompanyName(COMPANY_NAME);
        AdWhirlAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseAppName(APP_NAME);

        ;
        ZestAdzAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseAppName(APP_NAME);
        ZestAdzAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseCompanyName(COMPANY_NAME);



        AdManager.setPublisherId("a14ce50397c3043");



        AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout=new AdWhirlLayout(this,"XXXXXXXX");

        //handle(adWhirlLayout,this.Ration);

        final int DIP_WIDTH = 320;
        final int DIP_HEIGHT = 52;
        final float DENSITY = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int scaledWidth = (int) (DENSITY * DIP_WIDTH + 0.5f);
        int scaledHeight = (int) (DENSITY * DIP_HEIGHT + 0.5f);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adwp =
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(scaledWidth, scaledHeight);

        layout.addView(adWhirlLayout,adwp);
        layout.invalidate();



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("ad whirl", "un able to create adwhirl layout", e);
    }
```

Comment: How do you get that DEBUG/AdWhirl entries to show in LogCat? I use AdMob SDK and don't have that .setInTestMode option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had a similar problem,

try **double checking** if every network **sdk** is integrated (eclipse, settings, build path) and **included as jar file**.

Good look && best regards,
mike

edit:

hey Kariyachan, sry for replying so late, didn't realize the answer. Admob serves still very few ads.. zestadz doesnt support ads for german apps.. so it's a problem for me :(.... but i can recommend.. http://www.millennialmedia.com/... :=) they always have something to show... :) I'm really sorry.. my problems with ads have continued.. i also ain't get location based ads... that's the problem where i'm on now..

one more thing which **improved my ad performance**.. a**dd the AdWhirlInterface** (**implements**) to the activity u start your ads from.. and set the interface listener.. via code.. something like A**dWhirlAdapter.setInterfaceAdapter(this)** (if it is the current activity)

Comment: Thanks buddy 4 reply. i have added sdk in my appln for admob and adwhirl zestadz.I got the same result .I learned 4m ur profile that ur succed in getting ads from the admob.I think u can help me ,i updated my Q by adding code Cheers-:),Regards Kariyachan